# LWC not working in mobile app

Tags: lightning-web-components

If we have the LWC component on the quick action button that is working with the desktop but not for the mobile app, what could be the issue for the mobile app? Explain how we can resolve that.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. Code snippets will help massively, as will any info around what is seen on the mobile experience and whether you get any useful logs. As it stands, the question is likely to be closed without answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your LWC has no issue, but the mobile app doesn't support it.

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-quick-actions.html) (emphasis mine):

> Lightning web components are supported only as quick actions in Lightning Experience. **Using a Lightning web component as a quick action isn’t supported in the Salesforce mobile app**.

You could use an [Aura Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1_config_action.htm) as custom action if you need it in the Salesforce mobile app